# datatable.ajax.reload() with setInterval causes page crash, how can i avoid memory leak?

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

Here's my code, Ajax request for dataTable return 2000 rows of data. I want to update datatable every 2 seconds with new data. It is requesting 2000 rows of data every 2 seconds. But with setInterval the page crashes after 10-12 minutes because of memory error.
Is there any way to clear the memory without using *location.reload()*

```
var dataTable = $('#tblDemo').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "serverSide": true,
        url: "abc.php?data=getSomeData",
        type: "POST",
        data: {}
    },
    "pageLength": 15
});

setInterval(function() {
    dataTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `"destroy"` option to destroy old data.

Reference:: https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()

https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy - this worked for me! Thanks a lot!